# variable name will not change: evaluate string, save as dataframe variable

Tags: r

tldr version: I cannot rename the third variable. Here is the `dput` info:

```
> dput(head(transfer))
structure(list(pxcor = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), pycor = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), boarTerritoryStrength = structure(list(`count boars-here` = c(1.74067061418327, 
1.72108894667326, 1.80564895320475, 1.86442162955961, 1.96794014517206, 
1.97282628219563)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

On the chance that the process matters:

I am trying to evaluate a problem that will have variable length that looks like

```
(bh +
(b1 - bh) * (1 / 4) +
(b2 - b1) * (1 / 8) +
(b3 - b2) * (1 / 16) +
(b4 - b3) * (1 / 32) +
(b5 - b4) * (1 / 64))
```

bh through bn are dataframe columns. I found a nice decay function here

```
decind <- function(rate, index){
  iv = 1:index
  rate^iv
}
```

I have tried lots of different ways of using `purrr::pmap` but cant make it work. So I went back to what I know, generate text, and evaluate that text.

I get the counts I need in the form of a dataframe:

```
inRadius <- RNetLogo::NLGetPatches(c(coord,radius_list), patchset = "patches", as.data.frame=TRUE, nl.obj = nl.object)
```

A data frame like this (only much larger) is returned:

```
pxcor = c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
pycor = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
'count boars-here' = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
'count boars in-radius 1' = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
'count boars in-radius 2' = c(1,0,0,0,0,0)
'count boars in-radius 3' = c(1,1,1,0,1,1)

inRadius <- data.frame(pxcor, pycor, 'count boars-here', 'count boars in-radius 1', 'count boars in-radius 2', 'count boars in-radius 3')
```

where `count boars-here` = `bh` in the math above and so on...

I create a decay vector to multiply the differences by:

```
decay_index <- c(1,decind(rate = decay_rate,index = 3))
```

I then create the left side of the differences, excluding `bh`:

```
txt2 <- paste0("inRadius[",4:(r+3),"]")
```

and the right side:

```
txt3 <- paste0("inRadius[",3:(r+2),"]")
```

I am referring to them by position instead of name because the names returned by `RNetLogo` are not ideal (e.g. `count boars in-radius 1`) and my attempts at using `dplyr::rename` have been unsuccessful with generated strings of variables to rename.

Put the left and right together:

```
txt4 <- paste0("(",txt2, " - ", txt3,") * ",decay_index[2:length(decay_index)], collapse=" + ")
```

Add `bh`

```
txt5 <- paste0("inRadius$boarTerritoryStrength <- inRadius[3] + ",txt4, collapse = " + ")
```

Parse and evaluate:

```
inRadius$boarTerritoryStrength <- eval(parse(text = txt5))
```

**Here is where I am stuck without a workaround.** In spite of the fact that I can refer to `inRadius$boarTerritoryStrength` I cannot make the heading name change from `boarTerritoryStrength.count boars-here` to `boarTerritoryStrength` even when `names(inRadius)` returns `boarTerritoryStrength`. What is happening? I think it has something to do with the structure of the variable. When I reduce the dataframe to the variables of interest :

```
transfer <- inRadius[c("pxcor","pycor",'boarTerritoryStrength')]
```

and try to rename the variable I get the following result:

```
transfer <- dplyr::rename(transfer,boarTerritoryStrength = transfer[3])
Error: `boarTerritoryStrength` = structure(list(boarTerritoryStrength = structure(list("count boars-here" = c(1.74067061418327, 
1.72108894667326, 1.80564895320475, 1.86442162955961, 1.96794014517206, 
1.97282628219563, 2.11644489282094, 2.23824464253994, 2.12110353045762, 
2.0650885226467, 2.02798126531457, 2.05337715935252, 1.83241273580251, 
1.94819393076716, 1.76530065423594, 1.49416173465329, 1.39802937920689, 
1.24575433483398, 1.02206903695543, 0.853445962044646, 0.727744313331528, 
0.677242963610581, 0.629207842090238, 0.649596808294064, 0.620633145981629, 
0.709581297612886, 0.745212648875281, 0.846167659588047, 0.896615085966402, 
0.962433665031823, 1.09757092198464, 1.04520982017658, 1.17204722990454, 
1.24543078399972, 1.19204696623251, 1.20628338618684, 1.20454807527722, 
1.11692787493013, 1.03415111931798, 1.06042889007006, 1.01173626271344, 
1.00307658417938, 1.03234089328043, 1.06212347737113, 1.15538285142299, 
1.25632927295749, 1.35198259473356, 1.59989035012643, 1.6
```

Just using `names(transfer)[3] <- 'boarTerritoryStrength'` to try to brute force this thing does not change the displayed name.

In response to r2evans

```
> dput(head(transfer))
structure(list(pxcor = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), pycor = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), boarTerritoryStrength = structure(list(`count boars-here` = c(1.74067061418327, 
1.72108894667326, 1.80564895320475, 1.86442162955961, 1.96794014517206, 
1.97282628219563)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This question seems a bit overly complex way to say you cannot rename a frame's column name. I don't that *how* it is generated is relevant (at this point), it would help to be able to see the actual frame with which you are having trouble. I don't want to have to install `RNetLogo` just to do this, can you include the output from `dput(head(transfer))`?

Comment: I completely understand, should I edit all of that out? I have a hard time giving enough or too much detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the third column of `transfer` is not a normal vector, it is instead an embedded `data.frame`.

```
transfer[[3]]
#   count boars-here
# 1         1.740671
# 2         1.721089
# 3         1.805649
# 4         1.864422
# 5         1.967940
# 6         1.972826
```

(With a "normal" frame, `[[3]]` would have returned a vector, not a frame. Try `mtcars[[3]]` to see.)

There are several ways to get out of this. If this happens a lot, you may want something a little more programmatically "proper", but just a quick fix:

```
transfer[[3]] <- transfer[[3]][[1]]
transfer
#   pxcor pycor boarTerritoryStrength
# 1     0     0              1.740671
# 2     1     0              1.721089
# 3     2     0              1.805649
# 4     3     0              1.864422
# 5     4     0              1.967940
# 6     5     0              1.972826
names(transfer)[3] <- 'boarTerritoryStrength'
transfer
#   pxcor pycor boarTerritoryStrength
# 1     0     0              1.740671
# 2     1     0              1.721089
# 3     2     0              1.805649
# 4     3     0              1.864422
# 5     4     0              1.967940
# 6     5     0              1.972826
```

Comment: I agree with @Roland that your use of `parse(eval(...)))` should be discouraged. Unless there is something significantly different about the objects you've described, there is no benefit and plenty of detriments to using it. Just a thought; happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I don't condone use of `eval(parse())` for this. So, instead of following you into that rabbit hole, here is a better solution for the original problem:

```
DF <- data.frame(bh = 1:2, b1 = 3:4, b2 = 5:6)

with(DF, 
     bh +
       (b1 - bh) * (1 / 4) +
       (b2 - b1) * (1 / 8) 
)
#[1] 1.75 2.75

#programmatically, using matrix algebra
m <- as.matrix(DF)
m %*% c(1, (1/2 ^ (seq_len(ncol(m) - 1) + 1))) -
  m[, -ncol(m)] %*% (1/2 ^ (seq_len(ncol(m) - 1) + 1))
#     [,1]
#[1,] 1.75
#[2,] 2.75
```